# C - Segfaulting when trying to access atribute of initialized struct

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, attributes

I'm making my own version of malloc using a free list. For some reason my program is seg faulting when I try to access and change `newnode->size`. I'm not sure why this is happening as it is not a problem when I attempt to change `returnnode`. All I need to do is change `newnode->size` and
`newnode->next`.

For context this is my struct:

```
typedef struct freenode
{
    size_t size;
    struct freenode *next;
} freenode;
```

This is the area within my code that is causing the issue:

```
    curr = freelist;
    freenode *prev = NULL;
    freenode *returnnode = NULL;
    freenode *newnode = NULL;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        // Ignore this part
        if (curr->size - size <= 32 && curr->size - size >= 0)
        {
            returnnode = curr;
            if (prev)
            {
                prev->next = curr->next;
            }
            else
            {
                freelist = curr->next;
            }
        }
        // Error is being caused in this area
        if (curr->size - size > 32)
        {

            returnnode = curr;
            returnnode->size = size;

            newnode = curr + size;

            // Specific point of error
            newnode->size = curr->size - size;

            char str[18] = "\nmade it here\n";
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, 18);
            newnode->next = curr->next;
            if (prev)
            {
                prev->next = newnode;
            }
            else
            {
                freelist = newnode;
            }
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
```

I've tried making a temp freenode and realized it wouldn't work as I need the pointer to the new node to be at a specific point in the heap. Doing that would place it on the stack.

I've tried a bunch of other trivial things and nothing has worked.

Comment: 2 Issues here: `newnode = curr + size;`  1) This add `size * sizeof (*curr)` bytes, you probably only want `size` bytes. You may access your allocated memory beyond its limits. Lookup on pointer arithmetics. 2) You do not verify that the result is aligned properly. (Not causing your issue I guess)

Comment: You need to post the actual code where the nodes are actually (not being) allocated or there's no making sense of the problem.